# Firefox with profiles -- just use the default

Tags: windows-7, firefox

For quite a while, I have used Firefox on my Windows 7 laptop and a single profile.  When I open up Outlook or Pidgin or whatever, and I click on a link, that link opens up as a new tab in my Firefox window.  So far so good.

Now I have two profiles, one for regular day-to-day browsing, and one for work-related browsing with specific settings and proxies and whatnot.  I left the original profile with the name "default".  Now, however, when I click on a link in Outlook or Pidgin or whatever, I get the Profile Manager popup, asking me which profile I would like to use.  I select "default", and I get an error 'Firefox cannot use the profile "default" because it is in use.'

Clearly I have screwed something up that prevents Firefox from just opening a new tab in my default profile like it always used to.  But I can't figure out what that is.  Does anybody have a pointer?

This is my entire profiles.ini file

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/eo47sbrx.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=work
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/fakii06g.work
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found this post

[Is there a way to have Firefox profiles and switch between them?](https://superuser.com/questions/443822/is-there-a-way-to-have-firefox-profiles-and-switch-between-them)

which included this answer:

> ### About -no-remote switch
>
> - There's another parameter `-no-remote` which you can use to have **more than one profile opened at the same time**.
> - There can be max one Firefox instance opened without this parameter, and infinitely many opened with this parameter
> - You can also open Firefox always with `-no-remote` switch. **However**, this comes with a drawback. Read below.
>
> Keep mind that if:
>
> - Firefox is your default browser
> - you click a link in an external application (say, Word, PDF reader, or IM),
>
> then:
>
> - it will be opened in the Firefox instance opened without `-no-remote`.
> - **If you opened all instances of Firefox with `-no-remote`, you'll get an error message and the link will not be opened.**

This was my problem.  I was under the (mistaken) impression that all of my sessions had to have the -no-remote flag.  Thank you @jakub-g

Answer (score 0):

Your `profile.ini` seems to be correct, if the profile folders exist.

Try starting firefox from a shortcut using this

```
"C:\pathToFirefox\firefox.exe" -p "profileName" -no-remote
```

Also, create a shortcut to the profile manager, select default and click the `Use slected profile without asking at startup` this will set the default, instead of having to edit it manually as you did.

```
"C:\pathToFirefox\firefox.exe" -p
```

If the `Default` profile is broken, create another one and use it instead.